# Add comma and other words in string if boolean is false

Tags: c#, string

I have 3 booleans:

```
bool Boat, Plane, Car;
```

And 3 strings:

```
string ReloadBoat, ReloadPlane, ReloadCar;
```

Depending on these booleans, if false, I need to add commas between the strings and the word "and" between the last two strings.

```
string errorMessage = (Boat ? "" : " " + ReloadBoat + ", ") + (Plane ? "" : " " + ReloadPlane + ", ") + (Car ? "" : " " + ReloadCar);
errorMessage = errorMessage.TrimEnd(new[] { ' ', ',' });
```

For the above, the issue I am getting is, if both Boat and Plane are false, I am getting the errorMessage as "ReloadBoat , ReloadPlane".

I want it to be "ReloadBoat and ReloadPlane".

And if all the 3 booleans are false, then the errorMessage should be as:
ReloadBoat, ReloadPlane and ReloadCar.

Comment: If you have only 3 booleans + their strings, your code might probably be clearer if you just use a switch-statement, or a table-driven approach, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/xMpDxQ for an example

Comment: string.Join helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution (comments in code):

```cs
char comma = ',';

string errorMessage = (Boat ? "" : " " + ReloadBoat + comma) + (Plane ? "" : " " + ReloadPlane + comma) + (Car ? "" : " " + ReloadCar + comma);

// at first trim last comma
errorMessage = errorMessage.TrimEnd(comma);

// then replace the last separating comma with 'and'
int place = errorMessage .LastIndexOf(comma);
// only if comma is found
if(place >= 0)
    errorMessage = errorMessage.Remove(place, 1).Insert(place, " and");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool Boat = false, Plane = false, Car = true;
            string ReloadBoat = "ReloadBoat", ReloadPlane = "ReloadPlane", ReloadCar = "ReloadCar";

            var @string = new[] { ReloadBoat, ReloadPlane, ReloadCar };
            var @bool = new[] { Boat, Plane, Car };

            var zip = @bool.Zip(@string, (Bool, String) => new { Bool, String })
                           .Where(i => !i.Bool)
                           .ToArray();

            var lastIndex = zip.Length - 1;
            var delimeters = zip.Select((item, index) => index != lastIndex ? ", " : " and ")
                                .Skip(1)
                                .Append(string.Empty);

            var parts = zip.Zip(delimeters, (z, d) => string.Concat(z.String, d));
            var errorMessage = string.Concat(parts);

            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ReloadBoat and ReloadPlane
```

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally populate a list and then use a single line to create the message, allowing for additional items this way.

```
// start with a list
var errItems = new List<string>();
if (boat) errItems.Add(reloadBoat);
if (plane) errItems.Add(reloadPlane);
if (car) errItems.Add(reloadCar);

// make the error message     
var errMsg =
    errItems.Count > 1 ?
    $"{string.Join(", ", errItems.ToArray(), 0, errItems.Count - 1)} and {errItems[errItems.Count - 1]}" :
    errItems.Count > 0 ? errItems[0] : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list to hold all error strings.

```
List<string> msgs = new List<string>();

if(!Boat)
    msgs.Add(ReloadBoat);
if(!Plane)
    msgs.Add(ReloadPlane);
if(!Car)
    msgs.Add(ReloadCar);
```

Build message by string count.

```
switch(msgs.Count)
{
     case 0: return string.Empty;
     case 1: return msgs[0];
     case 2: return msgs[0] + " and " + msgs[1];
     default:
          string last = msgs[msgs.Count - 1];
          msgs.RemoveAt(msg.Count - 1);
          return string.Join(", ", msgs) + " and " + last;
}
```